# Getting wrong results with Harversine Forumla in C++

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to calculate the distance between London and Manchester using the haversine formula for my programming homework.

The given formula is

```
To calculate the distance between two places knowing their latitudes lat1 and 
lat2 and longitudes long1 and long2:
Convert all latitudes and longitudes from degrees to radians, then:
dLat = lat2 - lat1
dLong = long2 - long1
a = sin^2(dLat/2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin^2(dLong/2)
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
distance = R * c
where R is the radius of the Earth, 3958.75 miles.
Check: you should find the distance between Manchester and London to be 162.66 miles.
```

My code is

```
double hav_formula(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2){
    // Haversine Formula
    // Calculates distance between two places
    double dlat, dlong, a, c, distance;
    dlat = (lat2 - lat1) / 180 * PI;
    dlong = (long2 - long1) / 180 * PI;
    a = pow(sin(dlat/2),2) + (cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * pow(sin(dlong/2),2));
    c = 2. * atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a));
    distance = 3958.75 * c;
    return distance;
}

    double man_lon_distance;
    man_lon_distance = hav_formula(53.48095,-2.23743,51.50853,-0.12574);
    cout<<man_lon_distance<<endl;
```

I get a value of 108.342 instead of 162.66. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you mixing degrees and radians?

Comment: I had already converted degrees to radians.

Comment: Have you stepped through and double checked your conversions to radians?  I'm worried about you not using brackets around ... / 180 * PI;

Comment: I can't see where you convert lat1 to radians...or lat2

Comment: Oh my. That's a terrible mistake from my part. Thank you so much for pointing it out.

Comment: Thats fine, everyone makes mistakes...I don't know if this means your Question should be deleted or not - thats up to a moderator... (See the SO help section) Or you can select an appropriate answer and mark it.  Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have neglected to nurse every lat/long into radians...

Please find additional temp variables `radLat1/2` below, plus I added bracket to your calcs which could *easily* be misinterpreted and you get an unexpected result.

```
double hav_formula(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2){
    // Haversine Formula
    // Calculates distance between two places
    double dlat, dlong, a, c, distance;
    double radLat1, radLat2;
    dlat = ((lat2 - lat1) / 180) * PI;
    dlong = ((long2 - long1) / 180) * PI;
    radLat1 = (lat1 / 180) * PI;
    radLat2 = (lat2 / 180) * PI;
    a = pow(sin(dlat/2),2) + (cos(radLat1) * cos(radLat2) * pow(sin(dlong/2),2));
    c = 2. * atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a));
    distance = 3958.75 * c;
    return distance;
}
```